# Modified Bessel equation with Gaussian source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying a system in which a neutral particle beam with a Gaussian profile of known width $w$ enters a plasma. The beam produces secondary particles, which diffuse and are ionised through a first-order reaction (volume rate proportional to density $n$ of secondaries). The equation governing the density profile of secondary particles away from a line source is the *modified Bessel equation*,

$$r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dn}{dr}\right) - \lambda^2r^2n = 0 \; , $$

which is solved by modified Bessel functions of the second kind, $K_0(\lambda r)$. My problem comes when I try to consider the profile inside the source beam; the RHS of the above equation becomes a Gaussian, $A\exp(-r^2/w^2)$, with $A$ a known constant.

At first, I thought I'd be able to convolve the solution to the Bessel equation with the Gaussian to get the overall profile, but when it turned out that the Bessel function has a singularity at the origin I realised this would not be possible. I haven't been able to find any suitable solutions online, so I'd be very grateful for any insight the SE community can provide.

Comment: 1)  Can you define each of the terms in your equation?

Comment: 2)  Is the incident beam neutral or ionized?
3)  If you have Bessel profile away from the source, can you superpose the Gaussian profile when near the source?
4)  How are you defining "near" versus "far from" the source?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: $r$ is the radial distance from the beam axis. $n$ is the neutral (beam) particle density. $\lambda$ is a constant of integration, equal to the square root of the reactivity divided by the diffusion coefficient. $w$ is the standard width of the Gaussian beam profile.  

The beam is neutral. Simply superposing the Gaussian doesn't work, because there's no way to escape the singularity at the origin. When I say "far from the source", I mean that the solution is valid when the beam can be treated as a pure line source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is about a mathematical method to solve a second order ODE describing a physical situation. The mathematical problem is of a standard nature: given a homogeneous, linear, second-order ODE, what's the solution of the inhomogeneous equation?

The general solution of the homogeneous modified Bessel equation (with index 0) is (using the notation of the question)

$$n(r) = c_1 I_0 (\lambda r) + c_2 K_0 (\lambda r) \; .$$

Note that it has two independent ("fundamental") solutions as is appropriate for a second order ODE. $c_1$ and $c_2$ are fixed by boundary conditions.

The general solution of the inhomogeneous equation is found in most texts on ODEs, or online [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx). Denoting the inhomogeneity by $g(r)$ (which in the question is a Gaussian), the solution becomes

$$n(r) = - I_0 (\lambda r) \int du \, \frac{K_0(u)g(u)}{W(I_0, K_0)} + K_0 (\lambda r) \int du \, \frac{I_0(u)g(u)}{W(I_0, K_0)} \; , $$

where $u = \lambda r$ and $W$ denotes the Wronskian,

$$W(I_0, K_0) = I_0 K_0' - K_0 I_0' \ne 0 \; ,$$

the prime denoting a derivative with respect to the argument $(\lambda r)$. The integration boundaries are to be chosen such that $n(r)$ obeys the appropriate boundary conditions.

I'd be surprised if the integrals could be done analytically, but numerically they should be feasible.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clear exposition and will allow me to implement the solution numerically. Thanks also for spotting and correcting my typo in the original question - I'd written the correct form down in my notebook, but transcribed it incorrectly! Regarding the fundamental solution, I'd found the general form as you state above but had implicitly set $c_1$ to zero given the nature of the problem ($n\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$).

Comment: Good old variation of parameters. Nice work.